# MVC - folders vs namespaces structure (C#)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

What is best practice when using MVC pattern in C#? Am I supposed to use folders or new namespaces? When using namespaces, I have to add references, which namespace who can talk to another… and that is good!

But when using namespaces and releasing my program and checking the .exe file, it creates three (Model, View, Controller) .exe files which have to be in the same folder to be able to run.

When using folders, they are not dependent on each other which means that I can move the "main" .exe to a folder instead of moving all three exe files and it works.

I’d say that splitting namespaces is better because you can set up which classes that can talk to each other’s using References. But I don’t like that I have to have three exe files in the same folder to be able to run it (namespace-style).

So, what is best practice  for this + pros and cons?

See screengrabs to see the difference in Visual Studio 2015:
[Different namespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54BwR.jpg)
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVDh7.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Best practice is always to have namespace and folder structure matching. Your question seems to be asking which one is better, but the answer is you need both.

Comment: To clarify: Should I make Model, View, Controller as folders in a namespace or make Model, View and Controller as three different namespaces?

Please have a look on my print screens.

Comment: Program organization is completely opinion based - C#/.Net allow pretty much any way of organizing namespaces/folders/assemblies (unlike Java for example). Feel free to set them up the way work best for your project.

Comment: I think you are mixing up your terminology. I think you are referring to Projects as Folders, assuming this is the case your question becomes: should I separate my models views and controllers into different projects, or separate folders within one project. If this is what you wanted to ask, please edit your question.

Comment: Side note: it is somewhat unusual to build each component of MVC into separate executable and set up cross-process communication between them... Usually one would have main exe and possibly one or more class libraries (DLL).

Comment: Case 1: About terminology, no I’m referring to folder as a folder, for example Model where I store model-classes and Controller which stores controller-classes. The folders are stored in one namespace.
Case 2: Here, I have one solution with three namespaces (Model, View, Controller).
I could make the question more open: What is best practice for MVC structure in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is - it depends. It depends on what is easier to understand for you or, in case you are working with someone else, what is easier to understand for all programmers working on this code.

In C# you can do absolutely everything combining folder structure and namespaces. For example you could have class `Car` in `SuperModels\ExtraModels\Models\Car.cs` and this class could be in `namespace MyProject.Controllers`. It would be super weird and probably everyone who would like to change your code would say nasty things about you in their minds (or even out loud!), but it would work.

I'm using MVC pattern in ASP.NET and there the default project structure is like on your second screenshot, so I (and probably everyone who used ASP.NET at least once) feel more comfortable with that. However I saw projects where there was separate class library project only for models and was referenced in second project with controllers and views. Every approach which you are okay with, is good approach - there is no such thing as *correct* project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces (and assemblies) are the pathways where the ***compiler*** looks for classes.

Files and Folders are the boxes where ***people*** look for classes.

We like to keep everything neat and tidy and easy to find, so normally matching the folder/file pathway to the namespace pathway is the simplest.

But,

Sometimes separating them is easier to work with. For example, creating MetaData classes for customised partial classes of auto-generated EF entities -

- You could keep the .edmx in a 'DAL' folder,
- the customised partial classes in 'Models' folder,
- And the MetaData classes in 'Models.MetaData' folder

The partial classes would be under the same namespace 'MyProject.Models', but in different folders so you can easily work with customising them, while keeping the auto-generated classes out of the way.

And you could use a fully qualified class name to link one to its MetaData class.

So this would be in the DAL folder;

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public partial class Entity1
    {
        //Auto-generated code here - 
        //Don't touch so you don't lose it if auto-updates occur

        public string foo { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

This would be in Models folder;

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MyProject.Models.MetaData.Entity1Metadata))]
    public partial class Entity1
    {
    }    
}
```

While this would be in Models.MetaData folder;

```
namespace MyProject.Models.MetaData
{
    public class Entity1Metadata
    {
     [DisplayName("Foo Display Text")]
     public string foo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think this is better, more neat and tidy, than having everything together in one 'Models' folder.